Pointer arithmetic with pointer to member
I have a pointer to member, e.g.
#include <cstdint>

struct Foo {
  uint64_t x;
};

void test(Foo& f, uint64_t Foo::* p) {
  (f.*p) = 5;
}

That works fine. However, let's suppose that I actually want to produce a pointer to the second half of x (we are safely assuming little endian):
#include <cstdint>

struct Foo {
  uint64_t x;
};

void test32(Foo& f, uint32_t Foo::* p) {
  (f.*p) = 5;
}

void test(Foo& f, uint64_t Foo::* p) {
  test32(f, reinterpret_cast<uint32_t Foo::*>(p) + 1);
}

This fails with the error:
error: invalid operands of types 'uint32_t Foo::*' {aka 'unsigned int Foo::*'} and 'int' to binary 'operator+'

Why is this, and how can I do this pointer arithmetic?
(And yes I know this seems like a bad idea. Please no "you shouldn't want to do this" comments.)

With reinterpret_cast<uint32_t Foo::*>(p) you break strict aliasing, and are in undefined behavior land.

And generally, please don't write code like that.

Read to the very end.

A pointer-to-member is not a pointer. You simply cannot do pointer arithmetic with it. It is not designed for that.

You can always just "resolve" the pointer-to-member -- so you have an address for that member on an actual object, which is an ordinary pointer that you can use for whatever you want to use it for.

@Timmmm We read that final comment, and we tell you it is just not a bad idea. We try to tell you it is illegal. (even if it does compile AND seems to run, that's what the undefined behavior is all about).  Really you should watch some cppcon videos on youtube regarding undefined behavior (the ones from 2017 are pretty clear)

My coworker wrote a great blog post why undefined behavior is bad, and how it can cause time travel.

This smells like XY problem. OP insists that pointer-to-member should be used, but no actual problem is specified. Instead, you've arrived at a destination and are seeking a path to get there. If you just want to modify the second half of the value, you can do this quite legally with bitwise operations. You can even copy a value into that memory via a char*.

Instead of trying to get "half a pointer", why not write a function that sets half the value of the full *p?

@Someprogrammerdude This doesn't look like UB. Instead it is ill-formed. Pointer arithmetic is not allowed on pointer to member.

@user12002570 I think what they mean is that obtaining and using a pointer-to-member to half a member is bound to require UB somewhere. For example, manually editing the value of a uint32_t Foo::* with knowledge of its binary representation, and trusting type punning to correctly dereference it to half of the uint64_t. Nasal demons everywhere.

This is not an XY problem. It was for a temporary hack. And yes I am aware that pointers to members are not pointers. In theory that doesn't matter; under the hood they're just integer offsets. And yes I am aware UB is bad. Show me a C++ program that has no UB. I literally said "I know this seems like a bad idea". You don't need to repeat that.

Under the hood it is usually an offset. Or an offset plus one. Or a binary complement to an offset. Or something similar. If you know what it is under the hood in your implementation, you can modify it (of course knowing the consequences).


Why is this

Because the standard specifically disallows this arithmetic on pointer to member. First note that pointer to member are not actually pointers.
Now, from expr.add:

For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to a completely-defined object type and the other shall have integral type.

The important thing is that the phrase "pointer to a completely-defined object type" does not include "pointer to member" as per basic.compound#3:

Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members. Pointers to incomplete types are allowed although there are restrictions on what can be done with them ([basic.align]).


Yes I am aware that pointers to members are not pointers. They are typed offsets. But you can do arithmetic on offsets! At least in theory. Seems like this was just too niche a use case to bother supporting.
